# Partitioning Data creates unexpected results

Tags: r

I am trying to partition my data to a 60% Training and 40% Test Set using the following code.

```
split <- sample.split(divdat, SplitRatio = 0.6)
split
train.div <- subset(divdat, split == "TRUE")
test.div <- subset(divdat, split == "FALSE")
```

However, when using this code it splits my data as if it were 50/50.  I have two hundred observations but and I get 100 observations for each.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Function `sample.split` splits not by row, but by labels. to do it should change the first argument of `sample.split` to column values where you store labels. Then you'll observe 60/40 ration of training/test sets. I.e.

```
library(caTools)
divdat <- data.frame(id = 1:10, chars = letters[1:10], labels = c("X", "Y"))
split <- sample.split(divdat$labels, SplitRatio = 0.6)
train.div <- subset(divdat, split == "TRUE")
test.div <- subset(divdat, split == "FALSE")
train.div
test.div
```

Output:

```
> train.div
   id chars labels
2   2     b      Y
3   3     c      X
5   5     e      X
6   6     f      Y
9   9     i      X
10 10     j      Y
> test.div
  id chars labels
1  1     a      X
4  4     d      Y
7  7     g      X
8  8     h      Y
```